# Google Sheets sum duration over 24 hours

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using google sheets duration to work out the length of time an event runs for by giving it a start and finish time and some of these events start before midnight and end after midnight.

The formatting works fine, but when i try to get a total number of minutes for all of the events in a day, all of the events that start before midnight and end after it give a - value.

Is there a work around for this?

Is there a way to force the next formula to use the displayed duration output?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgEA6.png)

Answer (score 5):

SOLVED!

=MOD(F2-E2, 1)

Yay me!